# PHP Headers. Ошибка

Tags: php, android, curl

Есть один сайт, хочу оттуда получить json данные. Запросы на сайт отправляются через приложение Android. Получилось сниффером взять все заголовки и get-параметры, которые отправляет приложение на сервер. Пробую отправить через curl/postman запрос на /mobile.aspx?access_token=token со всеми заголовками, но мне выводит Access Denied. Через сниффер смотрю, приложение отправляет запрос и получает данные.

Вопрос: может ли быть там проверка, если запрос отправлен не с приложения, то выводить Access Denied? Или может еще какие-нибудь дополнительные заголовки надо вставлять?

Comment: вы, возможно не все данные скопировали. Возможно, какое-то поле меняется со временем. Например, какой-то token генерируется в зависимости от текущего времени. В любом случае, судя по вашему вопросу, вы пытаетесь сделать что-то, чего владелец сайта не хочет.

Comment: Да, заметил, что меняется get-параметр "nonce". Вот только что получилось взять данные, все вывелось правильно. Второй раз обновил страницу - уже Access Denied. Вот только откуда генерируется этот "nonce"

Comment: &nonce=c7941b2d-9746-4ee8-bf30-f7e4c7057b2b Может получится как-то расшифровать? Это что-то связано со временем

Comment: nonce обычно это зашифрованный определенным образом номер запросса. Каждый раз к nonce добавляется 1, и шифруется. Расшифровать не помогу, т. к. это 1. Бесполезно в случае использования современных алгоритмов. 2. Они потратили свои деньги\усилия на создание сервиса, и явно не хотят, чтобы кто-либо другой им пользовался. Я сам не хотел бы, чтобы кто-либо занимался таким видом кражи моей интеллектуальной собственности, поэтому помогать не буду